# C# HttpWebRequest for Twitter OAuth 1.0 suddenly returning 401 on production servers

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-oauth

I have code that authorizes users to our website using the Twitter OAuth 1.0 API. It worked fine until about 5/9/2022 when our production servers started getting 401 errors with an error 32 in the returned JSON (saying could not be authenticated). The underlying code did not change.

On further investigation on my development workstation (running Windows Server 2016), the error is NOT happening there (my development workstation is not available on the Internet at large while the production servers go through some firewalls, etc - curious thing is that I'm getting a response from Twitter [401], just that it says it can't authenticate).

Can anyone think of anything else I can try to get the code to work on production servers? Here's the code snippet:

```
   private String GetTwitterTokenAndRedirectUrl(Guid guidState, out String strToken)
   {
      String strAuthFormat = "OAuth realm=\"twitter.com\",oauth_callback=\"{0}\"," +
                             "oauth_consumer_key=\"{1}\"," +
                             "oauth_nonce=\"{2}\"," +
                             "oauth_signature=\"{3}\"," +
                             "oauth_signature_method=\"{4}\"," +
                             "oauth_timestamp=\"{5}\"," +
                             "oauth_version=\"{6}\"";
      SortedDictionary<string, string> sdBaseStringParameters = new SortedDictionary<string, string>();

  String strURL = addSiteToURL(strCallbackURL, "twitter");
  String strApiVersion = "1.0";
  String strMethod = "POST";
  String strRequestTokenURL = "";
  String strAuthenticateURL = "";
  String strOauthConsumerKey = "";
  String strOauthConsumerSecret = "";
  String strSignKey = "";
  String strSignMethod = "HMAC-SHA1";
  String strContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

  //Get keys/secrets/etc from database

  TimeSpan Timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
  String oauth_Timestamp = Convert.ToInt64(Timestamp.TotalSeconds).ToString();

  String strOauthNonce = Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(guidState.ToString())); 
  sdBaseStringParameters.Add("oauth_version", strApiVersion);
  sdBaseStringParameters.Add("oauth_consumer_key", strOauthConsumerKey);
  sdBaseStringParameters.Add("oauth_nonce", strOauthNonce);
  sdBaseStringParameters.Add("oauth_signature_method", strSignMethod);
  sdBaseStringParameters.Add("oauth_timestamp", oauth_Timestamp);
  sdBaseStringParameters.Add("oauth_callback", Uri.EscapeDataString(strURL));
  //sdBaseStringParameters.Add("include_entities", "false");
  //sdBaseStringParameters.Add("realm", "twitter.com");

  StringBuilder sbBaseString = new StringBuilder();
  sbBaseString.Append(strMethod);
  sbBaseString.Append("&");
  sbBaseString.Append(TwitterEncode(Uri.EscapeDataString(strRequestTokenURL)));
  sbBaseString.Append("&");
  //sbBaseString.Append(TwitterEncode(Uri.EscapeDataString("realm") + "=" + Uri.EscapeDataString("twitter.com&")));
  foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in sdBaseStringParameters)
  {
     sbBaseString.Append(TwitterEncode(Uri.EscapeDataString(entry.Key + "=" + entry.Value + "&")));
  }

  String strBaseString = sbBaseString.ToString().Substring(0, sbBaseString.Length - 3);

  String strSignature = "";
  strSignKey = TwitterEncode(Uri.EscapeDataString(strOauthConsumerSecret) + "&");             using (HMACSHA1 hasher = new HMACSHA1(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strSignKey)))
  {
     strSignature = Convert.ToBase64String(hasher.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strBaseString)));
  }

  String strAuthHeader = string.Format(strAuthFormat,
                                        Uri.EscapeDataString(strURL),
                                        Uri.EscapeDataString(strOauthConsumerKey),
                                        Uri.EscapeDataString(strOauthNonce),
                                        Uri.EscapeDataString(strSignature),
                                        strSignMethod,
                                        oauth_Timestamp,
                                        strApiVersion);

  ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

  HttpWebRequest objRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create($"{strRequestTokenURL}?oauth_callback={Uri.EscapeDataString(strURL)}");
  objRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", strAuthHeader);
  objRequest.Method = strMethod;
  objRequest.ContentType = strContentType;
  objRequest.ContentLength = 0;

  objRequest.Date = DateTime.UtcNow;

  strToken = "";
  WebResponse objResponse = SubmitRequest(objRequest, strMethod, "Error requesting email: ");  //Fails in this call
.
.
.
private HttpWebResponse SubmitRequest(HttpWebRequest objReq, string strMethod, string strErrorText)
   {
      HttpWebResponse objResp = null;
      try
      {
         objResp = (HttpWebResponse)objReq.GetResponse();  //Fails here and goes to the catch block
```

TIA,
Owen

Comment: check ur api key?

Comment: Thanks for the reply: the api key is coming from the same db connection on both production and on my developer workstation, so they should be the same.